# access to a std::vector contained by another class

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am still relatively new to C++, learning as I go, and I'm confused as to what is the 'best' way to expose the vector to its consumers. I'm not worried about performance.

I have a class that contains a vector of `raw data`. I have other classes that need to consume and process that vector.

From reading other posts here I'm not sure whether to return a `const` reference to the vector or expose `const iterators` as none of the consumers will modify the vector.

Is one way better than the other? Are there other options or other things to consider ?

```
typedef std::vector<int> RawNumberContainer;
typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator RawNumberIterator;

class RawData
{
public:
  RawData();

  void addNumber(int number)
  {
    rawNumbers.push_back(number);
  }

  // this?
  RawNumberContainer getRawNumbers() { return rawNumbers; }

  // or this?
  const RawNumberContainer& getRawNumbersConstReference() { return rawNumbers; }

  // or this?
  RawNumberIterator getRawNumbersBeginning() { return rawNumbers.begin(); }
  RawNumberIterator getRawNumbersEnd() { return rawNumbers.begin(); }


private:
  RawNumberContainer rawNumbers;
};

class Something;
class RawDataConsumer
{
public:
  // ??
  Something* processRawData(RawNumberContainer&);

  // ??
  Something* processRawData(const RawNumberContainer&);

  // ??
  Something* processRawData(RawNumberIterator begin, RawNumberIterator end);
};
```

Comment: Instead of names like `getRawNumbersBeginning()` and `getRawNumbersEnd()`, you could just choose `begin()` and `end()`. They're better,and your class will behave like containers, and you would be able to use it in range-based `for` loop as well.

Comment: Consider const iterators too

Comment: Or, you can just forget about all this class stuff and use vector directly... I mean, if all your `RawData` is going to do is hold a vector and expose the vector's public methods, then it's... kinda useless, you know. You said you have some other class that needs to consume and process that vector. Well, don't you think it would be nice to also hold the data it's working on?

Comment: @jrok The example is contrived for asking about accessing a vector.  'RawData' in reality, does have members other than the vector.

Comment: Neither, use visitors. With c++11 and lambdas it's a sinch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It:

```
const RawNumberContainer& getRawNumbersConstReference() const { return rawNumbers; }
```

And it:

```
Something* processRawData(const RawNumberContainer&);
```

Comment: This was my preference. I think this better shows the intent that the vector is not meant to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RawNumberContainer getRawNumbers() const { return rawNumbers; }
```

This way you'll make sure you can't edit the vector (only read-only access) and spare you of another variable being manually declared in your code.